# Formating the_terms() function output

Tags: custom-taxonomy, functions, taxonomy, terms

This code:

```
<?php the_terms($post->ID, 'type') ?>
```

Gives:

```
<a href="/archives/type/image" rel="tag">Tag</a>
```

What do to if I want to display only "Tag" word, not link eg.

```
Tag
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you can specify separators and such in `the_terms()` arguments, it assumes that you actually want links.

You can discard unwanted HTML by using filter:

```
add_filter('the_terms', 'no_terms_links', 10, 2);

function no_terms_links($term_list, $taxonomy) {

    if ('type' == $taxonomy)
        return wp_filter_nohtml_kses($term_list);

    return $term_list;
}
```

Or just use deeper [`get_the_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) function and iterate through its return to build your own markup.

Comment: I've added your code, but I'm still getting links :(

Comment: Don't forget to change `type` to your actual taxonomy in snippet.

Comment: At a super-duper simple scale, what about just `echo strip_tags( get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'type') )` ?

Comment: Yeaah, that would do it... I deem today - the day of overthinking code. :)

Answer (score -1):

At a super-duper simple scale, what about just:

```
echo strip_tags( get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'type') )
```

Comment: What about it? Does it work? What does it do? Is this an answer and how does it help?